# How to load VM_global_library.vm for Velocity in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, velocity

We're using a VelocityLayoutServlet as the view resolver in Spring Boot.

```
@Bean(name = "velocityViewResolver")
public VelocityLayoutViewResolver velocityViewResolver() {
       VelocityLayoutViewResolver resolver = new VelocityLayoutViewResolver();
       this.properties.applyToViewResolver(resolver);
       resolver.setLayoutUrl("layout/default.vm");
       return resolver;}
```

We want to load global macros from a ***VM_global_library.vm*** file, as described in the [Velocity User Guide](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/user-guide.html). Expected Velocity to load that default file from /templates directory, but not happening.

Adding theexplicit setting mentioned in the Velocity User Guide did not work either:
    spring.velocity.velocimacro.library=VM_global_library.vm

> velocimacro.library - A comma-separated list of all Velocimacro template libraries. By default, Velocity looks for a single library: ***VM_global_library.vm***. The configured template path is used to find the Velocimacro libraries.

Are we missing some magic, or is this missing from the integration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Velocity properties can be set with "spring.velocity.properties.*" attribute.
This configuration works for me:

```
spring.velocity.properties.velocimacro.library=templates/VM_global_library.vm
```

Comment: Thanks! Obviously the missing piece was ".properties" in the property - great catch! I now see in Spring Boot common props they have a setting for "spring.velocity.properties.*=" but we obviously missed that detail!